# Safari on iOS waits 10-30s before loading JavaScript at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, delay, latency

I'm looking for help understanding a bizarre loading delay on iOS. I have this exact HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<img src="img/potatoes0.png"/>
<img src="img/potatoes1.png"/>
<img src="img/potatoes2.png"/>
<img src="img/potatoes3.png"/>
<img src="img/potatoes4.png"/>
<img src="img/potatoes5.png"/>
<img src="img/potatoes6.png"/>
<img src="img/potatoes7.png"/>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

…plus eight identical images of potatoes and a copy of jQuery, all hosted on a remote web server.

This page loads pretty much instantly in a normal browser, but Safari on an iPhone (or in the iOS simulator on my computer) waits 11 seconds before loading the JS:

[image]

- The images all load basically at once, then the browser waits around 10 seconds before starting to load the JS.
- I've confirmed with Wireshark that the request doesn't go out until around the ten second mark, the delay is *not* server-side.
- If I add more images, the delay increases (e.g. to 30 seconds), even though the images still take well under a second to all load.
- If I add more JavaScript files, the browser loads them all simultaneously after the delay.

What the heck is going on?

Comment: No `<body>` element?

Comment: @Duopixel Unless you'd like to start the `body` with an element that can also appear in the `head`, it's optional in HTML5 and starts as soon as a non-`head` element (`img`, in this case) appears. I tried adding one, though, and no change.

Comment: @Sidnicious I am facing a similar issue. The delay in my case is always around 31-32 seconds. Were you able to find out ?

Comment: @detj I moved on to another project, and unfortunately I never tracked this down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is anything to do with jQuery or DOM load events.

I have encountered exactly the same problem testing on an iPod and iPad running iOS 9. I thought I was going nuts.

I created a file called test.js that contains this:

```
alert("test");
```

Placing this as a script include at the bottom of my page (just before the body close tag) introduces a significant delay before the file is executed.

Placing the file at the top doesn't cause any issues, so is my only solution currently.

Testing on various non-iOS devices and browsers does not show this problem.

@Sidnicious any chance you can test with a simple file like mine instead of jQuery?

Edit: I found a popular site that includes its JS at the bottom: 
[getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com). I visit that site on an iPod or iPad, refresh the page a couple of times and page loading freezes for 10-20 seconds before the JS loads.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not trigger until the entire DOM loads.

So, if you have a bunch of images - jQuery wont trigger till all of them are downloaded. To speed this up, try lazy loading your images.

One thing to note on Javscript in all forms as it applies to mobile browsers. If you have any kind of scrolling going on - Javascript will delay running until scrolling stops (this is to reduce battery drain on mobile devices by reducing the load on the processor). This may or may not be related to your issue, but should be noted whenever a JS problem arises only on mobile browsers.

Comment: All of the images load within the first two seconds. Safari is waiting until the ten second mark to start loading jQuery. (Nothing jQuery specific is happening here, the same thing happens if you replace it with a different JS file).